# How to get the decrypt the columns in asp.net web application from "always encrypted" columns in sql server

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-keyvault, always-encrypted

We have implemented the column level encryption in table using always encrypted wizards in sql server 2017 and the CMK is stored in Azure key vault. Can you please tell how to decrypt the column values while using asp.net web application.

Thanks.